# Possible to mixin ActiveRecord::Base instead of inheriting in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, abstract-class, mixins

I've written a module that acts as an abstract interface. I want to use it as a mixin for an ActiveRecord model in a rails app. I'm finding that if I mix it in, the abstract methods are effectively overloading the ActiveRecord::Base methods. For instance, accessors for database-backed attributes and methods like `save` are no longer defined as ActiveRecord::Base set them up originally.

What is the best way to get around this? My first thought is to somehow mix in ActiveRecord::Base after mixing in my abstract interface module, but I don't know if this is possible or has side effects.

Comment: I think you can define two modules, One define methods that doesn't exist in ActiveRecord::Base, another defines other methods and includes the first one. When you use a class extends ActiveRecord::Base, include the first one, or use the second one.

Comment: @Bigxiang That's effectively the same as not using the abstract interface, so that doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: I think that if you try to mimic abstract interfaces (two things nonexistent in Ruby) you're doing it wrong. Read about Ruby object model and try using models to achieve what you want!

Comment: @MichaelSzyndel Can you suggest a solution? I assume you mean relying on class inheritance, but that would mean I'd need to rewrite rails in order to tap into the ActiveRecord inheritance chain up-channel.